# How to do Simple Arithmetic validation in template part - django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to check total price and receiving price of user input which receiving price shouldn't be more than total price.

say example, I do have 3 input box. box a getting value of total price, box b getting value of receiving payment through card and box c getting value of receiving payment by cash. box b + box c should not greater than box a. I need to validate it and stop submitting it.

It may very simple, since I am new to django I posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#forms.py
from django import forms
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    a_value = forms.IntegerField(label='A value')
    b_value = forms.IntegerField(label='B value')
    c_value = forms.IntegerField(label='C value')

    def check_values(self):
        a = self.cleaned_data['a_value']
        b = self.cleaned_data['b_value']
        c = self.cleaned_data['c_value']
        if a > b + c:
            return True
        return False


#views.py
class Validate(View):

    template = 'validate.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = YourForm()
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = YourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.check_values():
                return HttpResponse('Values are valid')
            else:
                return render(request, self.template, {'form': form, 'error': 'Values are not valid'})
```